# Django Select2 get queryset

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset, jquery-select2

I've got a big problem with Django Select 2, because I want add to queryset request.user.
Here is my forms:

```
class Product(AutoModelSelect2Field):
    search_fields = ['name__icontains']

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(user=self.user)
        return queryset
```

and when I'm on my template, the select is blocked and on terminal I can see HTTP/1.1" 500.
I want to overwrite it:

```
class OrderProduct(forms.ModelForm):
    product = ProductChoicesPLN
    number = forms.IntegerField

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['product', 'number']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(OrderProduct, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['product'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(
            user=request.user)
```

but it doesn't works. Anybody got any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You get a 500 status code because an uncaught exception was raised. Please show the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: There is not an error, only info in terminal, when everything is ok, there is  HTTP/1.1" 200

Comment: There *is* an error, go to the URL that returns a 500 status code, you will see the backtrace if you have debug enabled.